# The "whens" argument to case(), when referring to a sequence of items, is now passed as a series of positional elements

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want query the sum() function on amount generated through the payment methods "cash" and "upi" separately.
Here is my cash and upi case.

```
cash_case = db.case([(Order.payment_method == 'cash', Order.amount)],else_=0)
upi_case = db.case([(Order.payment_method == 'upi', Order.amount)],else_=0)
```

Here is my query,

```
# query to filter desired response
    query = db.session.query(
        db.func.sum(Order.amount).label('amount'),
        db.func.sum(Order.pax).label('pax'),
        db.func.coalesce(db.func.sum(VehicalOrder.commission_amount, 0)).label('commission'),
        db.func.sum(upi_case).label('upi'),
        db.func.sum(cash_case).label('cash'),
        (db.func.sum(Order.amount) - db.func.coalesce(db.func.sum(VehicalOrder.commission_amount, 0))).label('profit'),
        db.func.date_format(Order.created_at, '%d %M %Y').label('date')
    ).filter(
        Order.created_at == date
    ).outerjoin(
        VehicalOrder, Order.id == VehicalOrder.order_id
    )
```

Comment: was throwing an error when using case(), sayings whens is not used. I removed the case clause and instead used condition check and added up the amount.

Answer (score 4):

The calls to `case` emit this error message:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: The "whens" argument to case(), when referring to a sequence of items, is now passed as a series of positional elements, rather than as a list.

As the error message explains, passing the `when` clauses inside a list is not longer valid, they should be passed like this:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa # just use db if using Flask-SQLAlchemy
cash_case = sa.case((Order.payment_method == 'cash', Order.amount), else_=0)
upi_case = sa.case((Order.payment_method == 'upi', Order.amount), else_=0)
```

or more generally:

```py
my_case = sa.case(
    (MyModel.foo == 'foo', 1), (MyModel.bar == 'bar', 2), else_=0
)
```

This change was added in SQLAlchemy v1.4 [as part of the future API](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_14.html#select-case-now-accept-positional-expressions), and replaced the previous behaviour in v2.x.